# Generator function with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, generator, pymongo

I am trying to make a generator function that yields an item on each call, however I keep getting the same item. Here is my code:

```
  1 from pymongo import Connection
  2 
  3 connection = Connection()
  4 db = connection.store
  5 collection = db.products
  6 
  7 def test():
  8         global collection #using a global variable just for the test.
  9         items = collection.find()
  10        for item in items:
  11                 yield item['description']
  12        return
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me (though you don't need to declare collection as global in this case, nor do you need the return statement). Perhaps there's an issue with how you're calling test()? I put four items into a collection with different descriptions, and running test() returned me an iterator with the four different items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, remove `return`, it's not necessary.

Your problem isn't with `test()` but how you're calling it. Don't just call `test()`.

Do something like:

```
for item in test():
    print item
```

And you'll get one item at a time. What this is doing is basically:

```
from exceptions import StopIteration
it = iter(test())

while True:
    try:
        item = it.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print item
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. Originally, I was trying to obtain an item using test().next()